# I'm trying to run this python script on button press in HTML, could anyone help me with it?

Tags: python

```
import speech_recognition as sr
import pyttsx3
import pywhatkit




listener = sr.Recognizer()
engine = pyttsx3.init()
engine.say('Is there anything i could do?')
engine.runAndWait()


def talk(text):
    engine.say(text)
    engine.runAndWait()


def take_command():
    try:
        with sr.Microphone() as source:

            print('Listening...')
            voice = listener.listen(source)
            command = listener.recognize_google(voice)
            command = command.lower()

    except:
        pass
    return command


def run_music():
    command = take_command()
    print(command)
    if 'play' in command:
        song = command.replace('play', '')
        talk('playing ' + song)
        print('playing')
        pywhatkit.playonyt(song)


run_music()
```

This is a simple command that listens to voice commands to play a song by using pywhatkit, I have tested this script and it works perfectly.

So basically I want to make so that if I press a button (with HTML), this command will run.
I am merely an amateur so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There are a number of Python web frameworks that could help you with this task. [Flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.1.x/) has been around for a while; it has good documentation and you'll find lots of information about it here on Stack Overflow and elsewhere. That might be a good place to start.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).